# How to reload page on indexedstack in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently i'm using `indexedstack` and `bottomnavigationbar`, there are two pages "HomePage" & "SearchPage". These two pages i put in a children inside `indexedstack` widget. Now the problem is

1. If i switch to Search Page or switch back to Home Page it does not reload the page. How to solve this issue using the current widget which is `indexedstack` widget.
2. Whenever i run the app it loads all the pages including Search page which is not a current page.

Below is the sample code.

> main

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: App(),
    );
  }
}
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AppState();
}
class AppState extends State<App> {
  static int currentTab = 0;
  final List<TabItem> tabs = [
    TabItem(
      tabName: "Home",
      icon: Icons.home_outlined,
      page: HomePage(),
    ),
    TabItem(
      tabName: "Search",
      icon: Icons.search,
      page: SearchPage(),
    ),
  ];
  AppState() {
    tabs.asMap().forEach((index, details) {
      details.setIndex(index);
    });
  }
  void _selectTab(int index) {
    if (index == currentTab) {
      tabs[index].key.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      setState(() => currentTab = index);
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        final isFirstRouteInCurrentTab =
            !await tabs[currentTab].key.currentState!.maybePop();
        if (isFirstRouteInCurrentTab) {
          if (currentTab != 0) {
            _selectTab(0);
            return false;
          }
        }
        return isFirstRouteInCurrentTab;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: currentTab,
          children: tabs.map((e) => e.page).toList(),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigation(
          onSelectTab: _selectTab,
          tabs: tabs,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> TabItem

```
class TabItem {
  final String tabName;
  final IconData icon;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> key = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  int _index = 0;
  late Widget _page;
  TabItem({
    required this.tabName,
    required this.icon,
    required Widget page,
  }) {
    _page = page;
  }
  void setIndex(int i) {
    _index = i;
  }
  int getIndex() => _index;
  Widget get page {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _index == AppState.currentTab,
      maintainState: true,
      child: Navigator(
        key: key,
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => _page,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> BottomNavigation

```
class BottomNavigation extends StatelessWidget {
  BottomNavigation({
    required this.onSelectTab,
    required this.tabs,
  });
  final ValueChanged<int> onSelectTab;
  final List<TabItem> tabs;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      items: tabs
          .map(
            (e) => _buildItem(
              index: e.getIndex(),
              icon: e.icon,
              tabName: e.tabName,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(
        index,
      ),
    );
  }
  BottomNavigationBarItem _buildItem(
      {required int index, required IconData icon, required String tabName}) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(
        icon,
        color: _tabColor(index: index),
      ),
      title: Text(
        tabName,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: _tabColor(index: index),
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Color _tabColor({required int index}) {
    return AppState.currentTab == index
        ? Colors.red
        : Colors.black;
  }
}
```